# MySql SELECT INTO Variable: returns null

Tags: mysql, select

I am using a select into variable query in two ways as follows:

1. `SELECT @var1:=columnname1, @var2:=columnname2 FROM tbname WHERE menuname='somevalue'`: **this is working**
2. `SELECT columnname1,columnname2 INTO @var1,@var2 FROM tbname WHERE menuname='somevalue'` : **this is not working in all cases** Returns null sometimes

Please can anyone guide me why the (2) query works only sometimes and which is the more appropriate way. While when I run query (1) for the same where condition as in (2), it gives me results.

Comment: If the first version is working, then use that.  The second should work.  You need to explain how and when the second is not working.

Comment: that is what I want to know why the second one is not working everytime

Comment: Let us know in which case it is not working

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu as described `menuname=somevalue` . I am new in using this kind of query . For same menuname value 1st works and other `returns null`.

Comment: try this: SELECT columnname1,columnname2 INTO @var1,@var2 FROM tbname WHERE menuname='somevalue' limit 1

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu thank you for your response but it is still the same. Though  it helped me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem by using the following for query (2)

`SELECT columnname1,columnname2 INTO @var1,@var2 FROM tbname WHERE menuname='somevalue' limit 1; SELECT @var1;`

which now returns me the value of variable2. I was missing the `select @var1` statement

Thank you for all your help