# Select into variable not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

This is the mysql stored procedure to just print the fetched val from select query. Not sure where am i going wrong , it always prints `null`

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test(IN input VARCHAR(5000),OUT output VARCHAR(5000))
 BEGIN 
    DECLARE detail_id VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE val VARCHAR(128);

    SET output = CONCAT(output, "0", ':', "Starting");

    select split_string_new(input,':', 1) into val;

    SET output = CONCAT(output, "detail_id0---",detail_id,"....");

    SET detail_id = "";

    SELECT `dtl_id` FROM detail_tbl WHERE `dtl_val` = val INTO detail_id; 
    SET output = CONCAT(output, "detail_id1---",detail_id,"....");

 END $$
DELIMITER ;

call test('123',@output);SELECT @output;
```

I tried few solutions found on stackoverflow only like below and few more , but still unsuccessful. Any help on this will be appreciated !! 
[MySQL Stored procedure variables from SELECT statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649748/mysql-stored-procedure-variables-from-select-statements)
[MySql SELECT INTO Variable: returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36450605/mysql-select-into-variable-returns-null)

Comment: Please tag properly.  Which dbms are you using???????  MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: @Eric mysql    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Then remove the `plsql` tag!!!!!!!

Comment: Does split_string_new work?

Answer (score 1):

Try to put `INTO` clause before `FROM` clause.

```
SELECT `dtl_id` INTO detail_id FROM detail_tbl WHERE `dtl_val` = val;
```

Comment: I had tried that it stil gives me null. I tried with your above query, i tried with @detail_id as well .. no luck !!